# Are references non-nullable by default in F#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, reference

I know that in C# it isn't, and it is in languages like Haskell (if I am not wrong), so thought maybe F# also had the same semantics by default.

Also even though it doesn't exist in C#, it's a limitation of the language not the runtime, right? Like either F# or some other new .NET language can in fact implement this as a default without using any sort of hack.

Comment: Having such a language feature by itself isn't that useful if you're constantly using libraries which aren't designed with it in mind. Having all the standard APIs annotated with code contracts in .net 4 might make it feasible to work more with non nullable references.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. So if the library isn't designed with it, then you will run into lots of problems using the libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In F#, if you define a new class or other type in F# code, then it will be non-nullable by default, in the sense that e.g.

```
type MyClass() = ...
...
let x : MyClass = null   // does not compile
```

However it compiles down to .NET IL code as a class, which is a reference type on .NET, which can be null, and thus either C# could create nulls of that type, or even in F#

```
let x : MyClass = Unchecked.defaultOf<MyClass>
```

would give you a null.  So in that sense, it is very much a "limitation of the runtime" - you can never create a .NET language that can both "expose a class to C# so that it looks like a normal class" and also "ensure that instances of that type are never null".  So you always have to make pragmatic decisions here.  F# tries to prevent you from accidents and the annoyance of dealing with null when you stay inside F#, but if you deal with interop or .NET runtime details, at the end of the day null is always hanging around.  (Billion dollar mistake.)

Comment: Thanks, great post. I am surprised they didn't allow this to be done natively and supported all around the runtime, for other .NET languages.

Comment: Hindsight is always 20-20.  You either get this stuff right at the beginning, or else it's too baked to ever go back and change.  You could build a time machine and try to convince the .NET/CLR folks of this in 1999, but you'd probably fail, as they had their own slew of priorities back then.  Some warts aren't as obvious/painful until the whole thing has time to mature.  But this is the natural march of progress, and hopefully the next big JVM/CLR/whatever will get this right, and have generics and non-nullable reference types from day 1, and then all will be joy and light.  :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the points Brian raises, it is probably worth mentioning that when you define a new type in F# you can opt to allow `null` values if that's the behavior that you want.  This is done via the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type T1() = class end

type T2() = class end

let t1 : T1 = null
let t2 : T2 = null // compiler error
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your follow-up question, yes, this attribute applies to the type itself.  The vast majority of F# types will not have this attribute applied; if you have a function or method with a parameter which you want to allow to have either a valid value of the type or a "null-like" sentinel value, then you would use an `option` type:

```
let myFunc (o:option<T2>) = 
  match o with
  | None -> "No value passed in"
  | Some(t2) -> "A T2 instance was passed in"
```

Option types are similar to nullable types in C#, except that they aren't limited to wrapping structs (and some additional minor differences irrelevant to this topic).

Comment: Thanks, so this is done via attributes? But this is for the type itself, right? What if you have a type that can't be null, but you say you want it null for some value?

Comment: Thanks, so are options like Maybe types? Option seems strange to me, or does it mean option as in optional? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Also in your myFunc if you forget to check for `None` for `o` would it fail at compile time?

Comment: @Joan - yes, `option` in F# (and other languages in the ML family) is equivalent to `Maybe` in Haskell.  If you omit the `None` case, the F# compiler emits a warning (not an error).